# Removing dying stem of howea forsteriana

Tags: roots, stems

I purchased this Kentia Palm about 3 months ago now and since then one of the stems (back right in image) has been dying off. It does not seem to be the watering as the other stems are healthy, and if you look at the roots of the dead stem they seem to come up out of the ground.

My question is; how can I best remove it? Cut the stem off just above the ground, cut off the roots, or anything in between?

Besides this is there anything I should pay attention to when this stem is removed?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the brown stem is dead. It probably did not have as well developed a root system as it's larger neighbours.

If you twist it out you will damage the roots of the other stalks so just cut it off as cleanly as possible as low on the stem as possible.

Although Kentia's are sold as low light plants that is only true when they are well established.  Your plant would do better if situated in bright diffuse light such as a south window with light curtains.